# Reload fb:comments widget

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook App that allows people to create "Posters". Every "Poster" can be commented on using `fb:comments` widget.

User can switch between posters using AJAX. The problem is that after switching to next poster `fb:comments` widget is still pointing to previous URL. Is there a way to "reload" a widget for a new url?

Answer (score 12):

Ok, solved this by myself, leaving it here for reference.

If you want to reload `fb:comments` widget it's as simple as that:

```
// xid can only contain a-zA-Z0-9_%.-
comments_html = '<fb:comments xid="' + encodeURIComponent(xid) + '"></fb:comments>';
// #comments is a div, containing fb:comments element
$('#comments').html(comments_html);
FB.XFBML.parse($('#comments').get(0));
```