# Updating facebook comments plugin link without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-comments

This displays the comments from that **http://domain.com/some/abc**

```
<fb:comments href="http://domain.com/some/abc" num_posts="20" width="500"></fb:comments>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1234567890";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

If the user changes a value in the form from abc to xyz, I need the comment plugin to display comments from **http://domain.com/some/xyz** without reloading the page.

```
<form id="name">
    <select>
        <option value="abc" selected>abc</option>
        <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is it feasible? (didn't find any information on the fb dev page.) I'm using jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is feasible; I believe I managed to replicate your desired result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/94KMR/);

Snippet in case the jsfiddle dies:

```js
(function loadfb(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1234567890";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');

function changeDomain(value) {
    var newVal = '<fb:comments href="http://example.com/some/' + value + '" num_posts="20" width="500"></fb:comments><div id="fb-root"></div>';
    $('#comments').html(newVal);
    FB.XFBML.parse($('#comments').get(0),function(){
        $(".FB_Loader").remove();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="name">
  <select onChange="changeDomain(this.value);">
    <option value="abc" selected>abc</option>
    <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="comments">
  <fb:comments href="http://example.com/some/abc" num_posts="20" width="500"></fb:comments>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
</div>
```

I did it by first replacing the innerHTML of the comments div(that I created to house the fb:comments tag), and then calling [`FB.XFBML.parse();`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) on that same comments div.  Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872766/reload-fbcomments-widget) which alerted me of that method.

Comment: just a tip: the <div id="fb-root"></div> can be placed outside the #comments div. No need to re-create that div.

Comment: ++ just in case jsfiddle dies