# Is it same origin policy the prevents button loading? In this

Tags: jquery

I have a simple page with a Facebook like button on it. Works fine.

```
<fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" id="222" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

I have the following jQ:

```
$('.ajaxlink').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                    $('#222').empty();
                    $('.fbDIV').html('hello<fb:like href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="arial"></fb:like>');
            }
        });
  });
```

When clicking a link to populate a div with the same code exactly for the button but this time it doesn't work? Interested to know why...

[Here's a fiddle showing the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/6cN4Y/3/)

Comment: Ajax needs a URL to post to. By default it's posting to the current page.

Comment: My guess is the script that replaces the fb link only runs on window load, it doesn't run again when you add a new element with jquery.

Comment: You'll see here that ajax has absolutely nothing to do with it: http://jsfiddle.net/6cN4Y/7/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating facebook comments plugin link without reloading page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744420/updating-facebook-comments-plugin-link-without-reloading-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask FB XML to reparse the page by calling: `FB.XFBML.parse();`. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744420/updating-facebook-comments-plugin-link-without-reloading-page). I updated the fiddle to demo this: http://jsfiddle.net/6cN4Y/9/.

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using for the facebook button only gets elements that exist on window load. I suggest using another method for your facebook buttons, such as iframes.